# Display recent record

Tags: mysql, sql

i was trying to display recent record.
i insert sql below in the recordset

```
SELECT `date`, `item_name`, `stock_invent`, `id_invent`,`num_in_out` 
FROM `inventories` ORDER BY `id_invent` DESC LIMIT 3
```

But, how to make it display in table? because i got message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LIMIT 0, 10' at line 1

Comment: Your query doesn't have `LIMIT 0, 10`, so what you think you are running and what you are running would appear to be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, item_name, stock_invent, id_invent, num_in_out 
FROM inventories ORDER BY id_invent DESC LIMIT 0,3
```